# Does calling CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference do any network communication?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a class with a `readonly CloudBlobContainer`, and functions to do operations on `CloudBlockBlob`s inside. If I want to do multiple operations on a `CloudBlockBlob`, would I avoid unnecessary network activity (and the associated slowdown) if I only get the `CloudBlockBlob` reference once and pass it around to the functions? Or can I get the reference many times without worrying?

TL;DR: **Is `CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference` purely a local operation, so that it won't cause network activity if I call it?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is correct, `CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference` does not make network call. It simply creates an instance of `CloudBlockBlob`. However if you use [`GetBlobReferenceFromServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblobreferencefromserver.aspx), it does make a network call.

Comment: I came to think - what of the Etag? (`cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ETag`) How is that retrieved if it doesn't make a network call?

Comment: Since it is a server side property, you would need to make a network call. By default it will be empty. You can do `CloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributes` to populate this property.